# XML Parsing of API response using Python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-services

I am trying to parse the below response from restapi in python.

My requirement is to get the API URL for second api call from the reponse of first api call. Unfortunately the URL is not a separate TAG in the response.  It is mentioned as value of xlink:href with in tag itself as metadata as per my understanding.

xlink:href="http://thomas-bayer.com/sqlrest/CUSTOMER/"

The below is the response that i got for the first API call.

Full Response message for First API call.

[api response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YMba.png)

I have tried below in python. Can you let me know how to handle this in Python.
[python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/011Jo.png)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuI6d.png)